# how dynamically value fetch into combobox in struts?

Tags: struts

how dynamically value fetch into combobox in struts?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `html:options` tag.

Check this example http://leejeok.wordpress.com/2008/05/14/struts-html-options-tag-sample-code/